# Grails 3: Update domain fails due to Unique constraint violation

Tags: grails

I have the following abstract domain class. It's implemented according to the specs of the SpringSecurity **UserDetailsService**:

```
abstract class Users {
    transient passwordEncoder
    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'username'
        version false
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = passwordEncoder ?
                passwordEncoder.encode(password) : password
    }
}
```

And here's the domain class that I am using to implement it:

```
@Resource(uri="/userinfo")
class UserInfo extends Users {
    String name
    String title
    enum Status {
        ACTIVE,
        INACTIVE,
        UNCONFIRMED
    }

    Status status = Status.UNCONFIRMED
    static belongsTo = [organization: Organization]
    static constraints = {
        name blank: false
        organization nullable: false
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can create instances of UserInfo classes, but I cannot update them. Running the following code:

```
UserInfo userInfo = UserInfo.findByUsername "fakeemail@gmail.com"
userInfo.status = UserInfo.Status.ACTIVE
if(!userInfo.save()) {
    logger.error "Unable to save user updates"
    userInfo.errors.allErrors.each {
        println it
    }
}
```

results in the error:

> Field error in object 'com.UserInfo' on field 'username': rejected value [fakeemail@gmail.com]; codes [com.UserInfo.username.unique.error.com.UserInfo.username,com.UserInfo.username.unique.error.username,com.UserInfo.username.unique.error.java.lang.String,com.UserInfo.username.unique.error,userInfo.username.unique.error.com.UserInfo.username,userInfo.username.unique.error.username,userInfo.username.unique.error.java.lang.String,userInfo.username.unique.error,com.UserInfo.username.unique.com.UserInfo.username,com.UserInfo.username.unique.username,com.UserInfo.username.unique.java.lang.String,com.UserInfo.username.unique,userInfo.username.unique.com.UserInfo.username,userInfo.username.unique.username,userInfo.username.unique.java.lang.String,userInfo.username.unique,unique.com.UserInfo.username,unique.username,unique.java.lang.String,unique]; arguments [username,class com.UserInfo,fakeemail@gmail.com]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] must be unique]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could there actually already be 2 rows in your table with username='fakeemail@gmail.com'?  Possibly by someone entering the data in some other fashion, or before the constraint was added?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

As far as I can tell, nothing.  That looks like a bug in the validation support.

Comment: I have version set to false- do you think that might be the cause of error?

Comment: No, I doubt that is relevant.

Comment: This is currently happening to me on production, but everything runs fine on development. Also it comes up and goes as it pleases. Still havent been able to wold this issue